# text direction RTL and text align center is not working

Tags: css, right-to-left, text-align, text-indent

i am having some difficulty in rendering some inputs center.
I am using the RTL direction with some offset of indentation.

But when text-align center it is taking the indentation size into consideration thus center off the screen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKPrOx

```
.star-cb-group {
  font-size: 0; 
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Can anyone help to point me to the right direction on how to resolve?

Thanks

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to remove the numbers from the labels and remove the text-indent.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqKLxb

If you must keep the numbers in there you could remove the text-indent and hide the numbers by setting the labels to `visibility: hidden;` and setting the ::before elements to `visibility: visible;`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvVBdX

Comment: thank you. Interesting, i am having a hardtime using letter-spacing: 1em; Nothing happens when I apply this =(

Answer (score 0):

add these two lines and remove text-align:center
             width:100px;
    margin:auto;